# Is 2-DNF NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability

I want to know whether the 2-DNF problem is NP-complete or not? If it is NP-complete, can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: Please define the 2-DNF problem.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the matter?

Answer (score 14):

If you are referring to the problem of deciding whether a formula given in 2-DNF form is satisfiable, then it is in $P$, as well as general DNF satisfiability. Indeed, such a formula is satisfiable iff there is a clause that does not contain an inner contradiction. That is, a clause that does not contain both $p$ and $\neg p$ for some atomic proposition $p$. This can be checked in linear time.

Perhaps you are referring to 2-CNF? (Which is also in $P$, but it's less trivial.)

Answer (score 6):

An additional note to Shaull's answer.

Checking if a DNF formula $\phi$ is *valid* (i.e. is a *tautology*) is co-NP-complete.

Indeed a formula $\phi$ is valid if and only if its negation is not satisfiable. But if you negate a DNF formula and apply De Morgan's laws you get a CNF formula. So the problem is equivalent to CNF unsatisfiability.

But if you restrict to 2-DNF, the validity can be checked in polynomial time because the corresponding negated formula is equivalent to the (un)satisfiability of a 2-CNF formula (that can be checked in polynomial time).

Answer (score 2):

#2SAT and #2DNF are both #P-complete however.  #2SAT can be converted to #2DNF by taking a not of the equation and applying DeMorgans law.  If you have n literals then #2SAT=2^n-#2DNF, you subtract the total possible solutions from the number of unsatisfiable to get the number of satisfiable equations.  #2CNF reduces to #3CNF which reduces to #3CNF-balanced which reduces to the (-1,0,1) permanent which reduces to the {0,...,m} permanent which reduces to the (0, 1) permanent which is #P-complete per Valiant.  You could also likewise reduce #3CNF to #3DNF and then #3DNF-monotone (or convert to monotone while still at #3CNF) then reduce further to #2SAT-monotone.  And just like that you can circle around from #2SAT to #2SAT-monotone.  Regardless all of these problems and more are #P.